# How to write a function similar to Array.prototype.every() but for "almost every"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to write a function similar to Array.prototype.every(), but instead of returning true if every case is true, I'd like to give it a margin of error. Let's say I give it a margin of x, then it will return true if every case is true minus x. It should read like this:

"At most x elements do not meet the criteria"

For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, -1].almostEvery((n) => n > 0); //With a margin of 1
```

This would return true since only 1 of the values is less than zero

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this.length - this.filter(cond).length` to get your number of errors, and then check with `errors <= margin` to achieve the desired logic.

I added default `margin` of 1 for sensibility, so it doesn't behave like `.every()` by default.

```js
Array.prototype.almostEvery = function(cond, margin = 1) {
  const errors = this.length - this.filter(cond).length;
  return errors <= margin;
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, -1, -1],      // 2 errors
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3, -1, -1, -1];  // 3 errors

let greaterThanZero = (n) => n > 0;

console.log(arr1.almostEvery(greaterThanZero, 2)); // pass: 2 errors, margin 2
console.log(arr2.almostEvery(greaterThanZero, 2)); // fail: 3 errors, margin 2
```